# Android UI Problems

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-appcompat

I have a strange behaviour with the Android UI. At the beginning all works fine but after a minute the fragment always gets blank when replacing it with the FragmentManager. When reopening the app all looks fine again. I am using an AppCompatActivity does someone know a solution for this?

This is my replace code

```
        var fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, nextFrag).AddToBackStack("div_overview").Commit();
```

Edit:

I open the first fragment by using the following code in the MainActivity :

```
 SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.I‌​d.frameLayout1, fragments[1]).Commit();
```

This Fragment can open other fragments by button click. For this i am using

```
 var fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction(); fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, nextFrag).AddToBackStack("div_overview").Commit();
```

This behaviour only happens after some time (mostly after the screen has been darken). The first transactions are working without any problems...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you using appcompact activity so i think you have to use supportFragementmanager

Comment: What is `nextFrag`? Where do you initialize it?

Comment: don't post code here Edit your question and post there.

Comment: Should you use ChildFragmentManager for other fragments?